# Define an explicit isomorphism between $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+4 \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I know that $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(i)$.
I also know that $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+4 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(2i)$.
Since $\Bbb Q(i)$=$\Bbb Q(2i)$, it should be the case that $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+4 \rangle$. So may I ask for an explicit isomorphism between $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and  $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+4 \rangle$?

Comment: It might be a bit easier to think about this once we write one as $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and the other as $\mathbb Q[y]/\langle y^2+4\rangle$ (so we don't have the same variable. Now (informally) $x=i,y=2i$. Can you figure it out now?

Answer (score 5):

Define a map $f:\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb Q[x]$ by $f(x)=\frac12x$. The consider the composition

$$\Bbb Q[x]\overset{f}{\to}\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+4).$$

This is surjective because $f$ is, and you can check that the kernel of this composition is $(x^2+1)$, giving the desired isomorphism.

Comment: I am going to use the first isomorphism theorem by determining the kernel of the composition map. Let the composition be $\varphi$. It is easy to prove that $<x^2+1> \subset ker\varphi$. But how to prove the other direction?

Comment: @Y.X. Well note that $(x^2+1)$ is a maximal ideal (since the quotient is a field), so once you show $(x^2+1)\subset\ker\varphi$, you immediately know that $(x^2+1)=\ker\varphi$!

Comment: @AlexMathers What exactly do you claim is wrong with your answer?

Comment: The map i gave isn't a ring isomorphism, it doesn't send $1$ to $1$

Comment: @AlexMathers Why do you think that's true? My understanding of your definition of $f$ is that $f$ sends a polynomial $h(x)$ to $h(x/2)$, so in particular, every constant in $\mathbb{Q}$ is mapped to itself.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn oh ya you're right. Sorry, I misread my own answer. okay it's fine

Answer (score 3):

Define $\phi:\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2 + 1) \to \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2 + 4)$ by
$$
\phi(a + bx) = a + (b/2)x
$$
Per the comment, it's easier to think of this as $\phi:\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2 + 1) \to \Bbb Q[y]/(y^2 + 4)$, defined by $\phi(a + bx) = a + (b/2)y$.  Or, more simply, $\phi(x) = y/2$.